# How to derive address from private key?

Tags: private-key, public-key

I want to give users a private key so they can Easily get address..

Why? So a single series of digits enables them to have both public address and private key.

Of course this is for temporary use not for holding ether.

So the question is: how does one derive public address from private key?

Comment: Had a look at that one myself, but it does not really explain how to do it yourself on a programming level, imo.

Answer (score 3):

assuming you are using some sort of JavaScript in your endeavor,

consider using the useful [ethereumjs-util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-util) API.

Simply import it with: `require('ethereumjs-util');`

Specifically, you will want to use the function [privateToAddress(privateKey)](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/blob/master/packages/util/src/account.ts#L309).

It's all open source so you can browse through their code. Although you will find that all the Elliptic Curve operations are done using another library called `secp256k1`.

Hope this will help you achieve your goal.

Cheers, Simon

Answer (score 1):

Ive been using this: https://github.com/trapp/ethereum-bip44

Its JavaScript and it will give you a wallet and the private key that goes with it.

Comment: You get the wallet address using `wallet.getAddress(i)`. How do you get the corresponding private key?