# Send transaction with locked contract -> Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Tags: web3js, gas-limit, raw-transaction

I'm trying to send a transaction for a token with a locked contract. I'm doing this to find out when this contract will be open. So I'm expecting to get some kind of error like "ERC-20 Token Transfer Error (Unable to locate corresponding Transfer Event Logs), Check with Sender" or something, but I get this instead:

`Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value`

I saw a lot of articles about this and tried everything, but everything leads to the same error. Is it even possible to make an app check whenever contract will be open? My code:

```js
const main = async () => {
  console.log(`web3 version: ${web3.version}`);

  const myAddress = '0x...';
  const destAddress = '0x...';
  const transferAmount = 1;

  const count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress);
  console.log(`num transactions so far: ${count}`);

  const abiArray = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './contract.json'), 'utf-8'));

  const contractAddress = '0x...';
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contractAddress, { from: myAddress });

  const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(myAddress).call();
  console.log(`Balance before send: ${balance}`);

  const rawTransaction = {
    'from': myAddress,
    'nonce': '0x' + count.toString(16),
    'gasPrice': '0x09184e72a000',
    'gasLimit': '0x2710',
    'to': contractAddress,
    'value': '0x0',
    'data': contract.methods.transfer(destAddress, transferAmount).encodeABI(),
    'chainId': 0x01
  };

  try {
    const privKey = new Buffer.from(WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY, 'hex');
    const tx = new Tx.Transaction(rawTransaction);
    tx.sign(privKey);
    const serializedTx = tx.serialize();

    console.log(`Attempting to send signed tx:  ${serializedTx.toString('hex')}`);
    const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'));
    console.log(`Receipt info:  ${JSON.stringify(receipt, null, '\t')}`);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.error('Failed to send transaction');
    console.log(e.message);
  }
};
```

my wallet private key is in this format (example):
`7effd90c52ebcf6ff916a26e3053300ac10d4fecbcd0e46ae2ae861b120d8587`

P.S. I use `ethereumjs-tx` to make traction.

Comment: Your gas limit is too low 10k gas while minimum for a transfer is 21k gas. Try with 125k for a token transfer. And your gas price is too high 10,000 gwei (15gwei is suggested as fast in EthGasStation). I'd suggest to use [toWei](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-utils.html#towei) and [numberToHex](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-utils.html#numbertohex) to make your code more readable. Also run your test in some of the testnet to make sure everything is OK, rinkeby for example.

Comment: ok so if I want to set 0.000000015 as a gas price, how should I calculate it?

Comment: To convert from 15 gwei to wei do something like `web3.utils.toWei("15", "gwei")` or you if you want to use a number instead of a string you can combine with [toBN](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-utils.html#tobn), `web3.utils.toWei(web3.utils.toBN(15), "gwei")`.

Comment: setting limits to these would still return the same error `'gasPrice': '0x37E11D600',
    'gasLimit': '0x2DC6C0',`

Comment: Are you sure private key generates your address? Is chainId correct? Using ethereumjs-util you can generate address from private key https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15823/how-to-derive-address-from-private-key/15836#15836

Answer (score 0):

Your error indicates that the ether balance of `myAddress` is smaller than `0x2710 * 0x09184e72a000`.

Comment: good point! but the balance is kinda big there, what data there should be instead for gas price and limit? how to calculate it?

Comment: @ArnasPecelis: I have checked the balance of your account (`0xa288599936125Df4932Cf0B433c60D86cC74dafC`) on both mainnet and ropsten. It is zero on both. What network are you on?

Comment: I don't know how did you got this but that's not my account. I'm on mainnet and have two tokens in my account - ETH and one secret.

Comment: *Insufficient Balance* refers to Ether, not to any token that you may or may not have in your account. The account that I have checked matches with the private key that you have posted.

Comment: I can see on etherscan these: EtherValue: $4.42 (@ $147.43/ETH). So I'm sure that I have ETH to send transactions. That was an example of the key I do use. So I'm pretty sure thats a problem with gas limit and gas price

Comment: @ArnasPecelis: Please check how much ether (in wei) you have at `myAddress`, and then verify that it is indeed smaller than `0x2710 * 0x09184e72a000`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102026/discussion-between-arnas-pecelis-and-goodvibration).